# dynamic radio button value is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the value of the radio button with the following code. can you please any one let me know to get the value of the selected radio button.

```
<input type="radio" name="abc_181508" value="3" /> Reset                                                    
<input type="radio" name="abc_181509" value="1"  /> Approve
<input type="radio" name="abc_181509" value="0"  /> Reject
```

name is dynamic which is a listID

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your jQuery code please..?

Comment: Basics: `name` attribute should be same

Comment: The name of your radio must be the same i think. And can you post your code please ?

Comment: `I am trying to get the value of the radio button with the following code.`->where is the code for getting selected radio button value? did you even tried anything? Pls post your effort in your question.

Answer (score 0):

To get a single value you must have to use unique name like,

```
<input type="radio" name="abc" value="3" /> Reset                                                    
<input type="radio" name="abc" value="1"  /> Approve
<input type="radio" name="abc" value="0"  /> Reject
```

And get value like,

```
$('[name="abc"]:checked').val();
```